# Error sending emails concurrently with RazorEngine

Tags: c#, razorengine

We have a class library that parses email content using RazorEngine and sends the email using a web API client.

We use it to periodically send newsletters with a console application. This works pretty well as it can send 50k+ emails a day.

We also use it to send emails from our web application (for example, validation email after a user creates an account).

We are using the static method `Razor.Parse()`.

About 13% of emails sent produce the following error.

```
Cannot access a disposed object Object name: 'TypeLoader', source : RazorEngine, stackTrace :    
at RazorEngine.Templating.TypeLoader.CreateInstance(Type type) 
in RazorEngine\\src\\Core\\RazorEngine.Core\\Templating\\TypeLoader.cs:line 55

at RazorEngine.Templating.DefaultActivator.CreateInstance(InstanceContext context) 
in RazorEngine\\src\\Core\\RazorEngine.Core\\Templating\\DefaultActivator.cs:line 20

at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplate(String razorTemplate, Type templateType, Object model) 
in RazorEngine\\src\\Core\\RazorEngine.Core\\Templating\\TemplateService.cs:line 131

at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.Parse(String razorTemplate, Object model, DynamicViewBag viewBag, String cacheName) 
in RazorEngine\\src\\Core\\RazorEngine.Core\\Templating\\TemplateService.cs:line 435
```

This seems to happen because multiple emails are sent at once (other emails we send don't produce this error)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as we have no idea where this is comming from.

Comment: Likely you have a race where you dispose on one thread while using the same object on another thread. That's wrong, so stop doing that.

Comment: The service I'm calling is injected with Autofac using the scope InstancePerHttpRequest() so each email being sent should be using a seperate thread.

Comment: Well, already that sounds like a bad choice, even not considering the exception you're getting here. Would you hire one mail carrier for every letter you wanted to send? Think of threads as workers; you only hire workers when you have a lot of work for them to do.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same error, but on `RunCompile`.
After some experimentation, it turned out that we recreated the `RazorEngineService` for every email, from the same `TemplateServiceConfiguration`.
Although the latter is not `IDisposable`, something in it is.

Recreating the `TemplateServiceConfiguration` everytime, right before creating the `RazorEngineService` solved the problem.
However, so did reusing the `RazorEngineService`.
Apparently, once you have disposed of the `RazorEngineService`, something in the `TemplateServiceConfiguration` is also disposed of.

So, if you are sending multiple emails, either create the both `TemplateServiceConfiguration` and `RazorEngineService` for each, or create both once and reuse them.